# Подскажите в чем ошибка "Method AAA in BBB can not be applied to CCC"

Tags: java, android, строки, android-intent, arraylist

Выдает вот что:

> Method 'putStringArrayListExtra' in 'intent' can not be applied to '(java.lang.String, java.util.List)'

```
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] array= (getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tth_qsns));
arrayList = Arrays.asList(array);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v)
    {   
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StandartLayout.class);

        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("", arrayList);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Попробуй вместо пустых кавычек на 10-ой строчке что-нибудь написать. И Ещё,  подобное обсуждалось здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134983/liststring-to-arrayliststring-conversion-issue

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Метод `putStringArrayListExtra` вторым параметром принимает объект типа `ArrayList<String>`, вы передаёте объект типа `List<String>` на что компилятор справедливо ругается. Нужно начало изменить как-то так:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] array= (getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tth_qsns));
arrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StandartLayout.class);

intent.putStringArrayListExtra("", arrayList);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Опять ругается. Ведь метод addAll является типом boolean, а мы его применяем в `java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: @nikitoc, см. обновлённый ответ